# How to make my save/load to/from file function more canonical?

Tags: beginner, kotlin

I  started to learn Kotlin and am now looking for common ways to save object to file and then load an object from a file. In my case, I am saving `map<String, List<Int>>` and have feeling that my approach is not good enough.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
//    CreateDs.createLabeledList()
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, List<Int>>()
    map.put("first", listOf(1, 2, 3))
    map.put("second", listOf(4, 5, 6))
    val f = File("labels.txt")
    save(f, map)
    System.out.println(map)
    map.clear()
    load(f, map)
    System.out.println(map)


}

fun save(f: File, map: Map<String, List<Int>>) {
    f.printWriter().use { out ->
        map.forEach {
            out.println("${it.key}:${it.value.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "")}")
        }
    }
}

fun load(f: File, map: MutableMap<String, List<Int>>) {
    f.inputStream().bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
        lines.forEach {
            val parts = it.split(":")
            map.put(parts[0], parts[1].split(",").map { it.toInt() })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Converting a list of Ints to a comma separated string

```
map.forEach {
    out.println("${it.key}:${it.value.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "")}")
}
```

This could be refactored as:

```
map.map { (key, value) ->
    key + ":" + value.joinToString(",") { it.toString() }
}.forEach(out::println)
```

## Loading data into the map

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, List<Int>>()
map.put("first", listOf(1, 2, 3))
map.put("second", listOf(4, 5, 6))
```

This can be rewitten to use mapOf, which increases readability

```
val map = mutableMapOf(
        "first" to listOf(1, 2, 3),
        "second" to listOf(4, 5, 6)
)
```

## Destructuring declaration for splitting string

```
val parts = it.split(":")
map.put(parts[0], parts[1].split(",").map { it.toInt() })
```

Using a destructuring declaration may make the purpose of this code clearer.

```
val (key, values) = "a".split(":")
map.put(key, values.split(",").map { it.toInt() })
```